# How to add size to ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist of Ellipse2D , the user enter a number is joptionpane.showinputdialog , but he is allowed to enter any number , the problem if he exceed the size of arraylist I have a problem , i search a methode to increase the initial size of arraylist (I found ensurecapacity() but it dosen't work we must call it before we call the methode add?)
please help me

Comment: please post some sample code you tried..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ArrayList` resizes as necessary, so you don't need to do anything before calling the `add()` method. As you add items beyond the initial capacity of the list, the internal array will be expanded. Except for performance issues, the internal mechanisms and the capacity of the `ArrayList` shouldn't concern you.

The initial capacity is a useful thing to specify only if you know that you will insert a lot of elements to start with, in which case you want to avoid dynamically re-sizing the internal array continuously, but instead it's better to pre-allocate the necessary space in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To add elements to an `ArrayList`, simply call `add()` as many times as you need. This will automatically resize the list to accommodate the new elements.